# python string index out of range (a function works on one data won't work on another

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-mining, data-manipulation

```
def start_with_num(data,col):
    """
    This function is to get the information of whether the title starts with numbers
    """

    num=[]
    for item in data[col]:
        if item[0].isdigit() == True:
            num.append(1)
        else:
            num.append(0)

    return num
```

This is my code, it works perfectly fine on 2500 lines of train data

However, when I implemented it to the test data which contains 20,000 it 
gives me an error saying the string index is out of range

The function is to count how many strings start with a number by the way.

Here is the sample data on the column

```
0    UK’s response to modern slavery leaving victim...
1                                         this is good
2    The "forgotten" Trump roast: Relive his brutal...
3                 Meet the happiest #dog in the world!
4    Tokyo's subway is shut down amid fears over an...
5               Ban lifted on Madrid doping laboratory
6    Despite the ‘Yuck Factor,’ Leeches Are Big in ...
7    #China and #Pakistan have cemented their polit...
8    Malls are dying, but it's hard to profit from ...
9    Filipino troops kill notorious Abu Sayyaf kidn...
```

Comment: Hi, may I know roughly what a sample data would look like?

Comment: 0    UK’s response to modern slavery leaving victim...
1                                         this is good
2    The "forgotten" Trump roast: Relive his brutal...
3                 Meet the happiest #dog in the world!
4    Tokyo's subway is shut down amid fears over an...
5               Ban lifted on Madrid doping laboratory
6    Despite the ‘Yuck Factor,’ Leeches Are Big in ...
7    #China and #Pakistan have cemented their polit...
8    Malls are dying, but it's hard to profit from ...
9    Filipino troops kill notorious Abu Sayyaf kidn...

Comment: @chngzm here you go, thanks so much!

Comment: Could please you add a sample data (not all 20.000 but at least 2), the thrown error and t where it thrown (which line in your code)?

Comment: Errr may I ask what is the col supposed to represent in the data as well?

Comment: the data is called test_post the col is called 'postText' the column name is the same with two datasets

Comment: Is this a data frame? Please include all relevant information in the question please.

Comment: What does `data[col]` signify? Is it dataframe, one string or is a string split into something? Can you `print(data[col])` and show what does a sample output looks like?

Comment: Please post a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the  full traceback and minimal sample data reproducing the problem  please. Else it's crystal ball and wild guesses debugging, which has never worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an empty string in your data. You have to look for the string legnth to:

```
def start_with_num(data,col):
"""
This function is to get the information of whether the title starts with 
numbers
"""


num=[]
for item in data[col]:
    if len(item) > 0 and item[0].isdigit() == True:
        num.append(1)
    else:
        num.append(0)

return num
```

Comment: Far better way to check for a non-empty string: `if item ...`. The whole check should be `if item and item[0].isdigit():`.